# why doesn't my jar file run outside netbeans?

Tags: java, jar, build, execute

I built a jar file that can run perfectly within netbeans when I click run,
but when I try to run the jar file by double clicking it it does not run, nothing happens..

Comment: Run it from the command line and paste the error. Likely a class path issue, but who knows.

Comment: @DaveNewton how do I run from command line ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double-clicking the jar starts it, but unless you have a GUI application that opens a new window (in a different thread), it most likely finishes and closes before you can see anything.

In these cases you normally run the jar from the console (`java -jar ..`) to see if there are any exceptions/errors.

Answer (score -1):

Starting an application from the command line would let you debug the problem as Bozho said. But you need to check if you have all the files in dist folder that you need to run your program. For example if you are using a database file to get the data, you need to place this file in the dist folder after program is built. I think the jar file is using a relative path when looking for files.