# Jar file doesn't work outside the project folder

Tags: java, jar

My jar file doesn't work outside the project folder, unless i put it in the same directory as the lib folder. When i run the jar from command line i get this:

```
    C:\Users\Computer>java -jar SG.jar
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hiber
nate/cfg/AnnotationConfiguration
        at view.PessoaView.<init>(PessoaView.java:27)
        at view.PessoaView$7.run(PessoaView.java:291)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfigu
ration
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 16 more
```

The same with other "windows", cause my application has many menu itens. I have extracted the jar file, just to check and there's no lib folder there. I believe it should. 
The jar files needed for hibernate and all others required  are all in the lib folder. Can someone help?Thanks..
And here is a link to a similar question:

[why doesn't my jar file run outside netbeans?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8811589/why-doesnt-my-jar-file-run-outside-netbeans)?

Comment: *"unless i put it in the same directory as the lib folder"* - yes, that's how it works.  You jar file is likely to have a manifest entry which states the location of all dependent jars (class-path)

Comment: You "could" have a look at something like [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I'll check what you said, and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your jar does not includes dependancies that it requires for execution.

Your program requires hibernate jars. You can compile all dependancies with your current jar using maven.

Try this :
[Build jar with dependancies](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-build-a-jar-file-that-contains-its-dependencies.html)

Answer (score 0):

Jar file can not contain any other jar files. 
Some tools like ant, can pack several jars inside one you can take a look on the ant. 
Another way is directly specify class path to your libraries during running using `java -cp`  instead of  `java -jar`

Answer (score 0):

You can directly specify class path to the needed libraries during running using java -cp /